# answered reload session in codeigniter after updating profile pic

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i have this code its running but i want refresh my session when i update a profile pic the current pic will be change by the new pic i dont know what to do this part `$this->session->???` help would be appreciate

```
public function upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/default_image/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_width']  = '1000';
        $config['max_height']  = '1000';
        $config['min_width']  = '768';
        $config['min_height']  = '768';
        $config['max_size'] = '204800';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('funct/upload_image',$error);

    }else{
    $data=array('upload_image' => $this->upload->data());
    $id=$this->input->post('did');
    $info=$this->upload->data();
    $name = array('avatar' =>  $info['file_name']);
    $this->resize_image($data['upload_image']['full_path'],$data['upload_image']['file_name']);
    $this->user_model->get_image($id,$name);
    $this->session->set_userdata('avatar',$name);

    redirect('site','refreshed');

                }
}
```

Edit here is the answer my friend helped 
the solution was that in my session it was arrayed so he did he unset the arrayed loggin he made a new one still in arrayed form and then that is it he
fix it

```
public function upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/default_image/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_width']  = '1000';
    $config['max_height']  = '1000';
    $config['min_width']  = '768';
    $config['min_height']  = '768';
    $config['max_size'] = '204800';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('funct/upload_image',$error);

    }else{
    $data=array('upload_image' => $this->upload->data());
    $id=$this->input->post('did');
    $info=$this->upload->data();
    $name = array('avatar' =>  $info['file_name']);
    $this->resize_image($data['upload_image']['full_path'],$data['upload_image']['file_name']);
    $this->user_model->get_image($id,$name);

    //new session
     $result = $this->user_model->get_new_sess($id);


            foreach($result as $row)
             {
              $sess_array = array('id' => $row->id,
                             'F_name' => $row->F_name,
                             'L_name'=>$row->L_name,
                             'username'=>$row->username,
                             'email'=>$row->Email,
                             'avatar'=>$row->avatar,
                             'date' =>$row->registered_date,
                             'position'=> $row->name);
                $this->session->unset_userdata('avatar');
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
                        }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('item','Your profile is up-to-date');             
    redirect('accounts/view/'.$id);
                }
```

here is the edit part

Answer (score 1):

first you destroy you previous avatar session

```
 $this->session->unset_userdata('avatar');
```

the set new avatar session

```
$this->session->set_userdata('avatar',$name);
```

Comment: i didn't work when i refreshed it still the same thou in the database is already change

Comment: you do one this first you destroy all browser session and try it again.

Comment: $this->user_model->get_image($id,$name);$this->session->unset_userdata('avatar');$this->session->set_userdata('avatar',$name);

Comment: still not working i have to logout in order the effect to take place

Comment: have you use session library  $this->load->library('session');at your controller

Comment: sir is there a difference if  i autoload my session?

Comment: What do you mean my autoload my session i did'n get you?

Comment: on the config folder thier is autoload.php $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session');

Comment: it is same to $this->session->library('session');

Comment: use it is same to $this->session->library('session'); at the strating of your controller code

Comment: so what is the problem in my loggin here is the code foreach($result as $row)
     {
      $sess_array = array('id' => $row->id,
                     'F_name' => $row->F_name,
                     'L_name'=>$row->L_name,
                     'username'=>$row->username,
                     'email'=>$row->Email,
                     'avatar'=>$row->avatar);

        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
                }

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```
$this->session->regenerate_id();
```

Comment: does not work an error will occur and i research the code the code seems is not on codeigniter